# One byte character change on column name of generated sql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

We are facing a very strange issue on generated jdbc queries. Please look at the exception:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'cameramode1_.setupClassFame' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor461.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:90)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:342)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:187)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1791)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1864)
        ... 46 more
```

Somehow column name is generated as `setupClassFame` but actually column name is `setupClassName`. Our code is correct and it started suddenly on the running system, in other words we didn't make any changes. It happens sometimes and we see these type of changes in other queries.

There is one byte difference between N and F character, and the other changes on characters are also one byte (e.g. o and g).

We use java, hibernate and jdbc.

Do you have any idea? What could be the reason? What could be the work around?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue? I'm seeing a similar scenario in a hibernate application accessing mysql where data is being corrupted by a single bit flip which also started all of a sudden while the application was running without any changes introduced.

Comment: No, unfortunately, we couldn't find any solution. In addition, we couldn't find the root cause of this problem. After 2-3 days later, the problem disappeared and we have never faced it again. It's a very strange situation.